# Login failed for user 'devtestuser' - asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm struggling a little with getting my web application to connect to a database in SQL 2008 R2.  My connection string is:

```
<add name="EAssignmentDatabase" connectionString="Server=TSTCLSTR-TEST\TESTING;Database=JISCEAssignment;UID=testuser;PWD=Test12345;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I've noticed that within MS SQL Server Management Studio that the user has been setup inside the Database but there isn't a corresponding server (top level) login - could this be the reason?

Also i've tried creating a .UDL file to test the connection (SQL Server Native Client 10.0) and that is also giving a 'Login failed for user 'testuser' error.

If it is relevant I am using IIS 6.0.

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

p.s. also out of curiousity when I switch Integrated security on, then the app does connect to the db, but if i set it to off and manually supply my username and password into the connection string, it gives a login error.  Why is this?

Comment: Can you connect to the server using these credentials through the DBMS?
EDIT: Integrated security means BOTH SQL authentication and Windows authentication; when you turn it off - it means clients will have to use Windows authentication in order to connect to the DB

Comment: @Shai Im pretty sure Integrated Security means the opposite of what you say. With Integrated on you are only using your Windows Credentials.

Comment: @JiveBoogie, nope - that's incorrect. integrated means built-in, which means the username/password mechanism is *integrated* in the SQL server

Comment: @Shai from MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.integratedsecurity.aspx Integrated Security "Gets or sets a Boolean value that indicates whether User ID and Password are specified in the connection (when false) or whether the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication (when true)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the server should have "a corresponding server (top level) login". 
As I know the simplest way to fix your issue is to remove the user from Database and create him in the server level. You'll be able to grant him required permission on the JISCEAssignment database.

As for "Integrated security on" question, MS SQL Server has the following two authentication models: Windows & SQL Server. Integrated Security on means that Windows authentication is being used. If it's off then SQL Server authentication is being used, hence you need to specify SQL server user (for example sa user)

Here's an example on how to use SQL Server authentication:

```
Server=.;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can try  like this. may be it will help you.

```
<add name="EAssignmentDatabase" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```